# Does "mind your own business" refer to a physical action not a verbal expression that intervenes one's life?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

Normally, when someone **says** something or **expresses** something in words which intervenes our life.

For example, A saw B eating fast food. A, then, said to B "**Fast food is not good fro your health**" and B replied "**mind your own business**".

Can we use "**mind your own business**" for a physical action too, not a verbal expression?

For example, A was setting out the chairs and B did not say a word and he came and started to help A set out the chairs.

However, A was a fussy person. He wanted the chairs to be set out in the exact order he liked. A did not think that B put the chairs the way he liked.

Can A say "**mind your own business**" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you are not aware, *mind your own business* is an aggressive, often confrontational, comment.  As mentioned in other comments, *MYOB* is really only used to respond to **unwelcome inquiries** about your **private life** (and even then only certain inquiries from certain people). Outside of that usage, telling people to *MYOB* will often result in them taking offense to your comment.

You cannot respond to minor physical intrusions by saying *MYOB*.  Doing something like that would be seen as unacceptably aggressive and could escalate into a confrontation.  In your example, person A would first have to verbally engage person B before responding that way.

**SCENARIO 1 - no verbal exchange before the MYOB - confrontational usage**

This scenario is highly unlikely to occur because *MYOB* is generally not used this way.

Person B shows up and starts rearranging chairs.

Person A: Mind your own business.

Person B: You talking to me?  Why don't you f*** off a****le.

**SCENARIO 2 - verbal confirmation before the MYOB - inappropriate usage**

Person B shows up and starts rearranging chairs.

Person A: What are you doing?

Person B: I thought you needed some help with the chairs?

Person A (civil response): I'm very picky about how the chairs are arranged.  I kind of like to do it myself. [In this situation Person A and B remain on speaking terms and Person A still gets to arrange the chairs.]

Person A (uncivil response): Well why don't you mind your own business. [In this situation Person B throws away person A's lunch several times over the next year.]

**SCENARIO 3 - verbal confirmation before the MYOB - acceptable usage**

Person B shows up and starts rearranging chairs.

Person A: What are you doing?

Person B: Becky told me alcoholism runs in your family so I figured you were probably hung-over this morning and needed some help.

Person A: Do me a favor and mind your own business.  I'm fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes A can say "mind your own business", as in this case its physically, I would not say "verbally". "mind your own business" means for one to refrain for interfering or disturbing someone "physically", so in both cases you gave, "mind your own business" can be used.

For the second case, it means A wants B to "go away" and stop disturbing A, "disturbing" meaning either by talking to him or moving the chairs.

I would use 'mind your own business' only to respond to an unwelcome enquiry about my private life, e.g. 'Is your mother an alcoholic?' then you would reply 'Mind your own business'. If someone tries to interfere in a job or role that I consider to be mine exclusively, I might say e.g. 'don't interfere [with what I am doing]' or 'you stick to your job and I'll stick to mine'. - @MichaelHarvey

Comment: I would use 'mind your own business' only to respond to an unwelcome enquiry about my private life, e.g. 'Is your mother an alcoholic?'. If someone tries to interfere in a job or role that I consider to be mine exclusively, I might say e.g. 'don't interfere [with what I am doing]' or 'you stick to your job and I'll stick to mine'.

Comment: 'MYOB' can be a response to unwelcome negative comments as well as impertinent questions (as in Tom's fast food example).

Comment: @KateBunting, but do we say 'MYOB' for physical actions (no comments or talking involved) as mentioned in the 2nd example?

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I wouldn't use it that way.